# BitArray to byte[] wrong conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, byte, bitarray

I am implementing Huffman Encoding, the Huffman algorithm works well, the thing is:

When I'm trying to convert BitArray to byte[] using

```
BitArray encoded = huffmanTree.Encode(input); // The encoding works well
byte[] bytes = new byte[encoded.Length / 8 + (encoded.Length % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 1 )];
encoded.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
```

It converts wrongly. I wrote the byte array to a file, and then read it, and converted it to BitArray again, to see if it is the same:

```
//Displaying BitArray
        Console.Write("Encoded: ");
        foreach (bool bit in encoded)
        {
            Console.Write((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

//Writing to a file
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\vvvoh\source\repos\Laba1Alg\Laba1Alg\Encoded", bytes);
     
// Reading from file
        byte[] bytes1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\vvvoh\source\repos\Laba1Alg\Laba1Alg\Encoded");
// To BitArray
        var bits = new BitArray(bytes1);
//Displaying BitArray after reading from file
        Console.Write("Encoded again: ");
        foreach (bool bit in bits)
        {
            Console.Write((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Here is the output, it shows the code, the BitArray before conversion, and after.

```
Origin: ABC
Code:
A - 10
B - 11
C - 0
Encoded: 10110
Encoded again: 10110000
Final: ABCCCC
```

Please let me know where is my mistake, help me to understand where am I wrong.

Comment: You can’t save less than 8 bits. You have to store the information of how many bits you actually have separately, otherwise there’s no way of knowing how many of the 8 are in use.

Comment: How may I do that?

Comment: Write a number saying how many bits you have into the file in addition to the actual data